# Precise angle calculation

Tags: wpf, math, rotation, transformation

I am working on a project in which i have to rotate a tyre based on the value from the position sensor. Sensor provides values from 261(at -90 degree) to 395(at +90 degree). I am using `TransformGroup` so almost at 327 value from sensor the tyre should be straight and erect[image].

When value is 395 then tyre will totally lie along X axis similar is case for value 261. I am able to move the tyre but i am unable to calculate precise angle.
My way of calculation is like that i calculate the number of values btween the default value or zero value(327) for a specific angle(say 3). so i get number of values for that angle. Then i divide this number from the angle(3 degree). So i get angle for one value.

```
float tempangle = value from sensor-zero value which is 327;
                tempangle = Math.Abs(tempangle);
                tempangle /= float.Parse(angle for reference say 3 degree);
                tempangle = 1 / tempangle;
```

Here i put some body of known angle under sensor(which have an agle of degree). When i want to find some angle for some value i just multiply this angle with the number of values between that value and default value(327). So i get the angle to rotate the body.
suppose i have got angle after calculation

```
angle for one sensor value =1.14286286
```

Suppose i calculate angle by calculator like

```
1.14286286 *2=2.2857
1.14286286 *3=3.42858
1.14286286 *4=4.57145
1.14286286 *5=5.714314
1.14286286 *6=6.85717
```

As you can see that angle is skipping some decimal values. Is there any way to co op with it?
thanks

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: I mean one value is 2.2857 and second value is 3.42858, if it is possible that i could get value like 2.5 after 2.2, it should not step over to 3 right after 2.2. My method is unable to calculate in between values.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if I understand your problem, but a method that calcaluates an angle between -90 and 90 degree from an input value in the range 261 to 395 would simply look like this:

```
private static double SensorValueToAngle(double value)
{
    const double sensorMin = 261;
    const double sensorMax = 395;
    const double angleMin = -90;
    const double angleMax = 90;

    return angleMin + (angleMax - angleMin)
        * (value - sensorMin) / (sensorMax - sensorMin);
}
```

Comment: Does (angleMax - angleMin) multiply with numerator or denominator?